# i would like the remove .php from my website

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

am facing challenges to locate where .htaccess file is  on my ubuntu 22.04 online server i have insatlled apache2 on the server already and allow AllowOverride All but still nothing is happened

i have created .htaccess in the website directory and put the following code in but still nothing has changed

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

## To internally rewrite /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

but code work perfectly on my localhost

Comment: So what does your http server's error log file say? Maybe that the rewriting module is not loaded? Or that the configuration file is not readable?

Comment: Also please be more specific in your question (there is an "edit" button, use it to enhance the question): how _exactly_ and where did you implement the `AllowOverride` directive? Where exactly is that "website directory" located? What is the setting of the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`?